# I get the error 'script.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property'src' of null at script.js:13'

Tags: javascript, html

html file

```
<img id="mon" class="week" src="image/week/unmon.png" onclick="mon()">
<img id="tue" class="week" src="image/week/untue.png" onclick="tue()">
```

It exists like this.

js file

```
var d=new Date();
console.log(d.getDay());
if(d.getDay()=="1"){
week="mon";
document.getElementById("mon") = "image/week/check_mon.png";
document.getElementById("tue").src = "image/week/un_tue.png";
}else if(d.getDay()=="2"){
week="tue";
document.getElementById("mon").src = "image/week/un_mon.png";
document.getElementById("tue").src = "image/week/check_tue.png";
}
```

I did this.

And run it

> script.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property'src' of null at
> script.js:13

An error occurs.

How do I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you only call that script after the page is loaded! Otherwise, the script will try to get the element that is not yet present in DOM

Please refer to this answer: [Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $.ready() - how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Your HTML here

<script>
// self executing function here
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```